# SLiM autologin to wrong wm

Tags: autologin, slim

I configured my system to do an autologin using awesome wm. However, after an upgrade of my Debian Sid (which wasn't without difficulty because of a bug in the package of my graphic driver, I had to reinstall some packages such as SLiM before figuring out a solution.), SLiM is now using Gnome Classic as default WM.

My configuration is the following, feel free to ask me more information, I'll provide anything I can.

Relevant parts of `/var/log/slim.log`:

```
login_cmd           exec /bin/bash -login /etc/X11/Xsession %session
sessions            awesome,startxfce4,openbox,ion3,icewm,wmaker,blackbox
default_user        max
auto_login          yes
```

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I wrote `exec awesome` in the file `~/.xsession`.